# Jenkins "Invoke OWASP Dependency-Check NVD update only" not working

Tags: jenkins, owasp

we are using AWS & Jenkins and want to use the "OWASP Dependency Check"-Plugin. I tried to create a first job for the NVD update. The first step of this tutorial (https://blog.dominikschadow.de/2015/07/using-owasp-dependency-check-as-jenkins-plugin/) helped me. I did everything the same, except I left data directory empty.

While building the project everything seems to work fine and in the workspace i can see files with status downloading. After 11 minutes the build failed and workspace is empty.

Here is the console output:

```
Building remotely on default-7bzfp (jenkins-default-jenkins-slave) in         workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/dependency check/update nvd
[DependencyCheck] OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin v3.1.1
[DependencyCheck] Executing Dependency-Check with the following options:
[DependencyCheck]  -name = update nvd
[DependencyCheck]  -outputDirectory = /home/jenkins/workspace/dependency check/update nvd
[DependencyCheck]  -dataDirectory = /home/jenkins/workspace/dependency check/update nvd/dependency-check-data
[DependencyCheck]  -dataMirroringType = none
[DependencyCheck]  -isQuickQueryTimestampEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -jarAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -nspAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -composerLockAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -pythonDistributionAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -pythonPackageAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -rubyBundlerAuditAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -rubyGemAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -cocoaPodsAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -swiftPackageManagerAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -archiveAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -assemblyAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -centralAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -nuspecAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -nexusAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -autoconfAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -cmakeAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -opensslAnalyzerEnabled = false
[DependencyCheck]  -showEvidence = true
[DependencyCheck]  -formats = XML 
[DependencyCheck]  -autoUpdate = true
[DependencyCheck]  -updateOnly = true
[DependencyCheck] Data directory created
[DependencyCheck] Performing NVD update only
Agent went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$CloseCause: Buffer close has been requested
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.close(FifoBuffer.java:426)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport.closeR(NioChannelHub.j    ava:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:565)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF while receiving the data from     the channel. FIFO buffer has been already closed
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$3.run(NioChannelHub.java:618)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Build step 'Invoke Dependency-Check NVD update only' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

In 50% of the cases there is another output ending:

```
[DependencyCheck] Performing NVD update only
[DependencyCheck] Unable to update the Dependency-Check database
Build step 'Invoke Dependency-Check NVD update only' changed build result to 
FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I cant find any information about this problem in internet.

I already tried to

- set Request Memory to 1024Mi
- set Limit Memory to 1024Mi
- set Timeout in seconds for Jenkins connection to 300
- deactivate QuickQuery

Jenkins is running on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, verion 2.73.3.

I need your help, cause i ran out of ideas. If you need more information, please ask for I will reply you.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/1783 or 
https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/876
that is happening to me, once owasp is having connection issues to nvd, job fails, but local DB stays locked, in https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/1684 is mentioned to delete `~/.m2/repository/org/owasp/dependency-check-data/3.0` , I deleted `org/owasp/*` and helped temporary